# Why do I get this Method not found error anytime I click on a Sitecore template?

Tags: sitecore

We're using Sitecore 7.5 for our sites.  In the Content Editor, any time I click on a template, I get the following error:  Method not found: 'Boolean Sitecore.Data.Templates.TemplateField.get_IgnoreDictionaryTranslations()'.

I have no idea why I receive this.  It happens in both the Web and Master databases.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the version of the Sitecore.Kernel.dll I was using.  I was using version 7.5.4932.0.  Once I replaced it with version 7.5.5064.0 the error went away.